# C++ derived class unable to access protected members, unless default constructor is used

Tags: c++

Initializing fields within constructor works:

```
class Shape{
protected: 
float width,height;
public:
Shape()
{
    width = 13.2;
    height = 3.2;
}
}
```

However when using a constructor with parameters, the code no longer compiles:

```
class Shape{
protected: 
float width,height;
public:
Shape(float w, float h)
{
    width = w;
    height = h;
}
}
```

Triangle class:

```
class Triangle : public Shape{
public:
float area()
{
    return (width * height / 2);
}
```

Here is the main function:

```
int main() {
Shape s = Shape();
Triangle tri;

std::cout << tri.area() << std::endl;
return 0;
```

This compiles and outputs result:
21.12

However when using constructor with parameters `Shape s = Shape(13.2,3.2);`
it seems the Triangle object tri can no longer access the width and height of Shape class.

Comment: please post a [mcve]. I guess only little is missing from those fragments, but still it is missing

Comment: Please be more specific than "seems". What does the program do that makes it seem like that?

Comment: Your triangle instance isn't related at all to your shape instance.

Comment: `it seems the Triangle object tri can no longer access the width and height of Shape class.` what is the error message that you get from your compiler. I don’t think that the problem is `width` and `height` but that it can’t find a matching constructor for `Shape`  that is used by your `Triangle` class.

Comment: @tkausl what would be the correct way to implement something like this?

Comment: Once you write the code as "Triangle tri;", then the default constructor -Triangle() will be executed. So one of constructors - Triangle(), Shape() should be declared. If not you will be facing to compile error.

Comment: The access modifier on the instance data members is actually irrelevant, so the question title is misleading. You can verify this yourself by making `width` and `height` public instead of protected -- you will face the same compiler error. Andrey's answer explains the real issue.

Comment: The `Shape` object `s` has nothing whatsoever to do with the `Triangle` object `tri`. `tri` has its own `Shape` sub-object, and that gets initialized by the default constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that by defining `Shape`'s constructor with arguments, you disable the default constructor of `Shape` (or more precisely, define it as deleted). And since `Triangle` does not define a default constructor, it also gets marked as deleted.

You need to either define the default constructor of `Shape`, or define a constructor of `Triangle` that will call the constructor of `Shape` with parameters `w` and `h`.